# Resolving relative paths in Rollup and Webpack are different

Tags: webpack, rollup

In my module which is imported by a project, the path is being resolved differently in Rollup and Webpack. I'm therefore not able to publish my module for use because it will work inconsistently depending on the bundler being used.

In my module:

```js
// myModule/dist/index.js
const pkg = require("./package.json");
```

When imported via a user's project.

```js
// myProject/index.js
import myModule from `myModule`;
```

In **Rollup** this resolves as:

```
/Users/limitlessloop/Sites/myProject/package.json`
```

In **Webpack** this resolves as:

```sh
/Users/limitlessloop/Sites/myProject/node_module/myModule/dist/package.json
```

or in my actual case when using symlink for local testing

```
/Users/limitlessloop/Sites/myModule/dist/package.json
```

I've tried using `require(process.cwd() + "package.json")` but because of the case of compiling to a sandboxed environment (Figma plugin) without access to node, `process` does not exist and bundlers don't seem to support dynamic paths very well.

How can I achieve it so that my module references the user's current project directory when imported via their project?

Comment: You say you're compiling to a "sandboxed environment" but don't specify what it is.  What's your target?  You need to post a more complete example.  It looks like your NPM package (myModule) is being "built" by the parent project using parts of the parent filesystem which is a pretty weird pattern I've not seen before.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes you're right I should have given some context to that. I've updated my post. The target is "web" or common js. It's for a Figma plugin, so it's most similar to targeting for the browser, but not quite. Just to clarify, which of the two examples do you think are resolving as expected? The Rollup or Webpack output? I'm a bit unclear what `./` should be relative to.